# Mysql Data Types for decimal

Tags: mysql

I need to store data in a database and struggle to get my head around decimals or floats so need some help. The following are my expected ranges. I just need to know what data type I need to set for me columns in my Mysql database.

1) 7.2 - 9.2 (steps 0.2 so 7.4, 7.6,8.2 but also 8.0 etc) 
2) 0 - 10.0 (steps in 0.25 so 0.25, 1.25, 2.75 but also whole number 5.0 etc)

Comment: I would use DECIMAL in this instance

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `decimal` , `FLOAT` OR `DOUBLE`
MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values and eight bytes for double-precision values.

> FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means
>   than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D
>   digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined
>   as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed. MySQL performs
>   rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a
>   FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.
>
> When declaring a `DECIMAL` or NUMERIC column, the precision and scale
>   can be (and usually is) specified; for example:
>
> salary DECIMAL(5,2) In this example, 5 is the precision and 2 is the
>   scale. The precision represents the number of significant digits that
>   are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits
>   that can be stored following the decimal point. If the scale is 0,
>   DECIMAL and NUMERIC values contain no decimal point or fractional
>   part.

Example

```
CREATE TABLE analyzes (COL1 DOUBLE(10,4), col2 decimal(7,5) ) ;


INSERT INTO analyzes VALUES(7.2,7.2 ),(0.2,0.2),(5.0,5.0);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6efe6/1